# Appending data to a automatic partitioned dataframe stored externally as parquet files

Tags: pyspark

Trying to write auto partitioned Dataframe data on an attribute to external store in append mode overwrites the parquet files.

I have a huge amount of data that I cannot load in one go. So I am reading data a folder at a time in a loop. In every iteration, I partition the data based on a certain attribute and use saveAsTable to write the parquet files on Amazon S3. I am finding that my s3 folder is getting wiped out at every iteration. I want to add on the data from every iteration to my hive store in partitioned folders, so I can categorize the data and can read only the category I want to work on.

This is the command I am using to save the dataframe.

```
DF.write.partitionBy('Type').format('parquet').mode("append").saveAsTable(('AllComponents', path='s3a://xxx/<Path>')

for Pos1 in HexKey: 
    folderKey = "{}".format(Pos1)

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .getOrCreate()

    if DataSetSchema is None:
       log.warn("Reviewing schema")
       AllComponentsDF = spark.read \
         .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
         .load('s3a://location' + folderKey + '0/00/*')
       DataSetSchema = AllComponentsDF.schema
    else:
        log.warn("Reading folder {}".format(Pos1))  
        AllComponentsDF = spark.read \
            .format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
            .load('s3a://location/' + folderKey + '0/00/*', schema=DataSetSchema)
        AllComponentsDF.write.partitionBy('Type').format('parquet').mode("append").saveAsTable(('AllComponents', path='s3a://spark-cluster-boomi/AllComponents')
```

Comment: Why don't you try writing the parquet files in different folder options based on the defined values in Type since you are reading one at a time.

Comment: The raw data is a collection of nested folders and the files in the nested folders can be either of those types. So with an incremental folder "read" I will a separate grouping of data based on the same types which will have to be merged. I have petabytes of those small files. I do not want to re-read all those files for every type as it is very expensive. The file naming is a GUID value with no indication of the type by the name. You have to read every file to find the type.